# Silverlight - Automatically Iterate Through Images

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to create a constantly rotating display of special offers, new products and products that I want to promote using Silverlight.

I have all images loaded into my project. In the .xaml file I am loading the first image that I am trying to display:

```
<Image x:Name="Image1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="image1.jpg" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Visible" Loaded="onImageOpened">
    </Image>
```

And then in the code behind I am doing the following:

```
private void onImageOpened(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    CurrentImageIndex = (CurrentImageIndex == LastImageIndex) ? FirstImageIndex : CurrentImageIndex++;
    Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("image" + CurrentImageIndex + ".jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

but this does not seem to be working. The first image gets loaded fine and when I place a breakpoint on the onImageOpened, it gets to it once the first image is loaded, but it doesn't seem to change the image once the 1000ms elapsed. What am I doing wrong or is there a different way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use a timer to implement this. You could then replace the image every time the tick event is fired.

Here is the msdn link for creating a timer in Silverlight:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189084(v=vs.95).aspx
```

The timer would need to be started in the Loaded event and then stopped in the Unloaded event.